# JVM 64 is using a maximum of 2GB on Windows Server 2012 on Azure

Tags: java, windows, azure, jvm

I'm using a Windows 2012 server with 7GB of ram that is on Azure. 
I have installed 64 bit java on the machine.

When running the jvm, I have set the maximum heapsize to 4GB via the argument

```
-Xmx6g
```

However, when I'm running my jar, it encounter a java OutOfMemory exception. I have checked the task manager while it is running and it shows that memory used for the process peaks at around 2GB and never goes past that. This despite me setting heapsize to 6GB.

On my local PC, where I am using a Windows 7 machine with 8GM of ram, I do not encounter this issue.

I used the following commands in my java app

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
System.out.println("Max Memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
```

And it gives me the following:

Windows Server 2012

```
64
1670381568
```

Local PC

```
64
6681001984
```

Why is the Windows Server not allocating the full amount of memory to the JVM? Is there any setting that I am missing?

Comment: if you try and set the minimum heap size via `-Xms` does it do anything?

Comment: I've set -Xms3g but it doesn't help. The maximum memory is still the same and ram usage in Task Manager still peaks at 2GB.

Comment: Ok. This is really dumb and stupid of me but I figured out the cause of it.

I had placed the memory arguments at the end of my whole command line when I needed to put it just after the java command.

i.e. Instead of 
java -jar "myapp.jar" "myArgs" -Xmx6g

I should have used
java -Xmx6g -jar "myapp.jar" "myArgs"

Comment: Please post the answer then: http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really dumb and stupid of me but I figured out the cause of it.

I had placed the memory arguments at the end of my whole command line when I needed to put it just after the java command.

i.e. Instead of

```
java -jar "myapp.jar" "myArgs" -Xmx6g
```

I should have used

```
java -Xmx6g -jar "myapp.jar" "myArgs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the -Xmx parameter is not being considered or the process is not allowed to get more RAM from the OS.

My suggestions:

- Try using -Xmx4096m instead.
- Not familiar with Azure but I've read that there are ways to limit memory per process/shell. Could that be an issue here? (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(VS.85).aspx , taken from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ba92acf-e1b9-4a3e-8ae7-f8ac31723959/problem-with-running-java-application-into-a-win-vm-of-azure-by-using-powershell-remoting?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows )
- Finally, are the Java versions exactly the same on both places? (I mean, do you need a special Java JRE on Azure?)

Note: I would've used a comment since this is not actually a solution but I don't have the points yet. I apologize if this is not the correct way to contribute.